# Android writing over image in button

Tags: android

If I have a custom image can I write over it, will it always write to the center of the button image? Ie will setText on image always right to center of the image provided or do I need to do something to have this effect?  Thanks Also is it better to use ImageButton or set Image as background of Button? and write over it that way.  I want to use 3d images and write on top of them in black text.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is a preformance difference for using image button of a normal button, but I'd imagine that and image button will work better. Albiet I always just use a normal button and setBackground(...). Also if you want to set the text to always be in the middle, use android:gravity="center" in the layout file.